# Android OkHttp response broken encoding

Tags: java, android, okhttp

My android app have very strange random behaviour when i executing GET request using OkHttp, sometimes it has normal response body, but very often i have this

```
��������������Xm��6�+Q>�]y<��+[t� TH=X��Z��k�$��$���[�����<�f��r��q����5�����gE����|�c���y���y�|V�nVX�Q@����
```

and in this case http status everytime 200/OK

is somebody was in this situation?

Comment: Show the code of your request. Do you have `"Accept-Encoding"` in your header?

Comment: yes, gzip encoding,
`Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
                    .build();`
code is very simple

Comment: Remove the `"Accept-Encoding"` header. OkHttp wil handle the encoding for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit and OkHttp gzip decode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33889840/retrofit-and-okhttp-gzip-decode)

Comment: yea, it helps, thanks guys, Niels, you can post answer and i will check it as correct

Comment: I confirmed that removing ```.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")``` fixed the problem. Thanks.